# How to resolve ambiguity error in C++ after changing my file extension from c to cpp?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I changed the extension of my file `address2lineutil` from C to CPP.

When I was compiling with GCC with `.c` extension it compiled properly and worked fine. After I changed its extension to `.cpp` it's throwing these errors:

```
./../include/libiberty.h:112:64: error: new declaration 'char* basename(const char*)'
In file included from sysdep.h:48:0,
                 from address2lineutil.cpp:5:
/usr/include/string.h:603:28: error: ambiguates old declaration 'const char* basename(const char*)'

address2lineutil.cpp: In function 'void slurp_symtab(bfd*)':
address2lineutil.cpp:74:26: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'asymbol** {aka bfd_symbol**}' [-fpermissive]
address2lineutil.cpp: In function 'void translate_addresses(bfd*, asection*)':
address2lineutil.cpp:252:32: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

My address2lineutil.cpp headers:

```
       #include "sysdep.h"
        #include "bfd.h"
        #include "getopt.h"
        #include "libiberty.h"
        #include "demangle.h"
        #include "bucomm.h"
        #include "elf-bfd.h"
        #include "address2lineutil.h"
        #include <string.h>
        #include <execinfo.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <dirent.h>
        #include <unistd.h>

    static bfd_boolean unwind_inlines;  /* -i, unwind inlined functions. */
    static bfd_boolean with_addresses;  /* -a, show addresses.  */
    static bfd_boolean with_functions;  /* -f, show function names.  */
    static bfd_boolean do_demangle;     /* -C, demangle names.  */
    static bfd_boolean pretty_print;    /* -p, print on one line.  */
    static bfd_boolean base_names;      /* -s, strip directory names.  */

    static int naddr;       /* Number of addresses to process.  */
    static char **addr;     /* Hex addresses to process.  */
    static asymbol **syms;      /* Symbol table.  */

static void slurp_symtab (bfd *);
static void find_address_in_section (bfd *, asection *, void *);
static void find_offset_in_section (bfd *, asection *);
static void translate_addresses (bfd *, asection *);
```

Comment: For starters I recommend you use the *correct tags* for your question. C or C++? You can't have both.

Comment: the file is being converted from c to cpp. so i used both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ has different type-checking rules than C (at least than older "C").  It doesn't by default allow you to "get away" with things that C did.

You need to start learning how to interpret output errors.  Go open up "address2lineutil.cpp".  Go to line 74.  Look at the type being passed.  Undoubtedly it is type "void*".  But what is needed is type asymbol**.  Are you sure that what is being passed really *is* type asymbol**?  If so, you could just plain reinterpret_cast it.

In the same file, go to line 252.  You have a const char* and are trying to pass it (to a function probably) that wants char*.  A lot of older C functions require char* even though they don't change the string passed to them.  If you are certain this is the case, you could just const_cast it.

The above is merely a description of what you *can* do to make this compile.  As to what you truly *should* do, that I cannot tell you because I don't know your code.  Perhaps that function in line 252 that wants a "char*" can have it's signature changed to take a const char*?  Or, on the other hand, if it actually  changes the string it's given, then you should *not* just cast, but instead should create a non-const string buffer and pass that.

Really, what you *should* do is beyond the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. On redefinition of basename. This particular bug is in libiberty.h which isn't your code but from some third-party package. Update to a newer version of the package or fix it yourself. The easiest way is to just remove the bad redefinition from libiberty.h.
2. On invalid conversion. In C `void*` can be implicitly converted to another pointer type, but not in C++. You need to insert a cast.

Answer (score 1):

There's more to converting a program from C to C++ than simply changing the file name suffix and the compiler command that you use.  For instance, `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h` and `string.h` have been deprecated in C++ since 1998.  Instead, you should use `cstdlib`, `cstdio`, and `cstring`; then you can access their contents from the "`std`" namespace.  That should address your `basename` problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* basename(const char*)

const char* basename(const char*)
```

Imagine what happens if you call the function like that:

```
basename("test");
```

Will the result now be a `const char*` or `char*` ? Should the compiler generate a pseudo-random number and choose between them ?

If you have a class you can do it like that:

```
class Test
{
public:
    char* basename(const char*);
    const char* basename(const char*) const; //Assure that nothing in the class changes (except mutable)
};
```

If you don't, then choose between one overload and throw the other one in your recycle bin.
This is C++, not pure C.

Comment: `basename` is a standard function so seems odd that they've tried redefining it...or maybe they've just picked a poor choice in function name

Comment: Code in question is valid C, so there are no classes or overloads. The errors are elsewhere.

Comment: @ChrisTurner they didn't try to redefine basename.

Comment: @n.m. first line in the error output says otherwise